# Regex to match despite some of the characters not matching pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I'm working with some bioinformatics data, and I've got this sed expression:

`sed -n 'N;/.*:\(.*\)\n.*\1/{p;n;p;n;p};D' file.txt`

It currently takes a file that is structured such as:

```
@E00378:1485 1:N:0:ABC
ABCDEF ##should match, all characters present
+
#
@E00378:1485 1:N:1:ABC
XYZABX ##should match, with permutation
+
#
@E00378:1485 1:N:1:ABCDE
ZABCDXFGH ##should match, with permutation
+
#
@E00378:1485 1:N:1:CBA 
ABC ##should not match, order not preserved
+
#
```

Then it returns 4 lines if the sequence after `:` is found in the second line, so in this case I would get:

```
@E00378:1485 1:N:0:ABC
ABCDEF
+
#
```

However, I am looking to expand my search a little, by adding the possibility of searching for any single permutation of the letters, while maintaining the order, such that `ABX`, `ZBC`, `AHC`, `ABO` would all match the search criteria `ABC`.

Is a search like this possible to construct as a one-liner? Or should I write a script?

I was thinking it should be possible to programmatically change one of the letters to a `*` in the pattern space.

---

I am trying to make something along the lines of an AWK pattern that has a match defined as:

```
p = "";
p = p "."a[2]a[3]a[4]a[5]a[6]a[7]a[8]"|";
p = p a[1]"."a[3]a[4]a[5]a[6]a[7]a[8]"|";
p = p a[1]a[2]"."a[4]a[5]a[6]a[7]a[8]"|";
p = p a[1]a[2]a[3]"."a[5]a[6]a[7]a[8]"|";
p = p a[1]a[2]a[3]a[4]"."a[6]a[7]a[8]"|";
p = p a[1]a[2]a[3]a[4]a[5]"."a[7]a[8]"|";
p = p a[1]a[2]a[3]a[4]a[5]a[6]"."a[8]"|";
p = p a[1]a[2]a[3]a[4]a[5]a[6]a[7]".";
m = p;
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to make it programmatically for `n` numbers.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance .  In particular, check out `agrep` under the see also links, and have a read through that. I don't think commonly supported regexes will work for you, although awk may have some built in functionality for fuzzy matching I'm unaware of.

Comment: So you reserved first character? or you mean any three letter word?

Comment: I mean any 3 letter word. I should have probably written it more clearly

Comment: Is the `.*` before `\1` necessary?  Like right now `FEABCZ` would match.  That what you want?  It certainly simplifies the problem if it's not.  Also is `\1` always 3 characters?  That's small enough that you could brute force it by breaking into three capture groups and making sure you have `(\1\2[A-Z]|[A-Z]\2\3)`

Comment: Hey yeah `FEABCZ` should also match. Also, the sequence can be variable in length. I know that's frustrating :X

Comment: What about `ZABCDXFGHC`? (appending `c` to third case)

Comment: Yeah, as long as the string is found, allowing for one permutated letter inside the match. My pattern at the bottom works, but it's tedious, and only covers matches that are exactly 8 letters long

Comment: I think you should shed some light on problem. For example with found match `ABCD`, what are the rules to distinguish between `ABACD` and `BACD`? (first one should pass but second shouldn't). What are the rules?

Comment: I am looking for permutations at one spot. if ABCD is the pattern XXXXXABXDXXXXX should be allowed because it matches AB.D, but BACD does not match .BCD A.CD AB.D or ABC. In your examples, I don't think either should match.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, check this out where `fuzzy` is your input above:

```
£ perl -0043 -MText::Fuzzy -ne 'if (/.*:(.*?)\n(.*?)\n/) {my ($offset, $edits, $distance) = Text::Fuzzy::fuzzy_index ($1, $2); print "$offset $edits $distance\n";}' fuzzy
3 kkk 0
5 kkd 1
5 kkkkd 1
```

Since you haven't been 100% clear on your "fuzziness" criteria (and can't be until you have a measurement tool), I'll explain this first. Reference here:
http://search.cpan.org/~bkb/Text-Fuzzy-0.27/lib/Text/Fuzzy.pod

Basically, for each record (which I've assumed are split on `#` which is the `-0043` bit), the output is an offset, how the 1st string can become the 2nd string, and lastly the "distance" (Levenshtein, I would assume) between the two strings.

So..

```
£ perl -0043 -MText::Fuzzy -ne 'if (/.*:(.*?)\n(.*?)\n/) {my ($offset, $edits, $distance) = Text::Fuzzy::fuzzy_index ($1, $2); print "$_\n" if $distance < 2;}' fuzzy
@E00378:1485 1:N:0:ABC
ABCDEF
+
#

@E00378:1485 1:N:1:ABC
XYZABX
+
#

@E00378:1485 1:N:1:ABCDE
ZABCDXFGH
+
#
```

See here for installing perl modules like Text::Fuzzy
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/how-to-install-perl-modules-manually-and-using-cpan-command/

Example input/output for a record that wouldn't be printed (distance is 3):

```
@E00378:1485 1:N:1:ABCDE
ZDEFDXFGH
+
#
```

gives us this (or simply doesn't print with the second perl command)

```
3 dddkk 3
```

Answer (score 1):

**Awk** doesn't have **sed** back-references, but has more expressiveness to make up the difference.  The following script composes the pattern for matching from the final field of the lead line, then applies the pattern to the subsequent line.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
}

# Lead Line has 5 fields
NF == 5 {
    line0 = $0
    seq = $NF
    getline
    if (seq != "") {
        n = length(seq)
        if (n == 1) {
            pat = seq
        } else {
            # ABC -> /.BC|A.C|AB./
            pat = "." substr(seq, 2, n - 1)
            for (i = 2; i < n; ++i)
                pat = pat "|" substr(seq, 1, i - 1) "." substr(seq, i + 1, n - i)
            pat = pat "|" substr(seq, 1, n - 1) "."
        }
        if ($0 ~ pat) {
            print line0
            print
            getline; print
            getline; print
            next
        }
    }
    getline
    getline
}
```

If the above needs some work to form a different matching pattern, we mostly limit our modification to the lines of pattern composition.  By the way... I noticed that sequences repeat -- to make this faster we can implement caching:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS = ":"
    # Noticed that sequences repeat
    # -- implement caching of patterns
    split("", cache)
}

# Lead Line has 5 fields
NF == 5 {
    line0 = $0
    seq = $NF
    getline
    if (seq != "") {
        if (seq in cache) {
            pat = cache[seq]
        } else {
            n = length(seq)
            if (n == 1) {
                pat = seq
            } else {
                # ABC -> /.BC|A.C|AB./
                pat = "." substr(seq, 2, n - 1)
                for (i = 2; i < n; ++i)
                    pat = pat "|" substr(seq, 1, i - 1) "." substr(seq, i + 1, n - i)
                pat = pat "|" substr(seq, 1, n - 1) "."
            }
            cache[seq] = pat
        }
        if ($0 ~ pat) {
            print line0
            print
            getline; print
            getline; print
            next
        }
    }
    getline
    getline
}
```

Comment: Breaking it up like that...smart.  I need to start doing that.  Oh, and check out `gawk` `match`.  It supports capture groups.  Granted, it's a flavor, but...

Comment: @zzxyz -- thanks for the positive comment and the suggestion.  :)

Comment: It seems like this solves the problem for the sample I gave above! I am still trying to figure out where the fuzziness is build into this script

Comment: @Cayetano -- In the statement `m = "[" $NF "]"` I compose a *bracket expression*.  For instance, out of `"ABC"`, I am composing `/[ABC]/`

Comment: Ah right. That is brilliant. I guess I wasn't clear on the one aspect, that the order should be preserved, that is really my fault